# Memory loss after creating Xen DomUs

Tags: linux, memory, xen

I have CentOS 5.5 and this is my kernel: 2.6.18-194.11.1.el5.centos.plusxen
Regulary, my comuter have ~2G of memory. 
After creating Xen DomUs (2 domains 512 M memory each one) it down to ~1G, but it does not return to 2G 
even after all domains go sleep.

So, this is MemTotal line from /proc/meminfo directly after Dom0 boot:

```
MemTotal:      1777664 kB
```

And this is after I boot up and boot down 2 DomUs:

```
MemTotal:       980992 kB
```

This is output of xm list after I put domains down:

```
[~]# xm list
Name                                      ID Mem(MiB) VCPUs State   Time(s)
Domain-0                                   0      958     2 r-----   1819.9
[~]#
```

What I need for return the memory to Dom0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xen does not automatically reallocate memory to domain 0 once a domU has shut down. You will need to use `xm mem-set` to reallocate it manually.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. I only want to add for people who will read this, that domain id and memory in megabytes must be supplied after mem-set subcommand, and that maxmem value from output of xm list -l 0 (for Dom0) can be used.